# Как в одной таблице иметь несколько foreign keys?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring

Есть две отдельные таблицы.
Они в себе содержат ссылки пользователя на роль или полномочие.

Я ловлю ошибку, когда пытаюсь объединить ее в одну таблицу *users_authorities*

```
 user_id | role_id | permission_id                                                                                              
---------+---------+---------------                                                                                             
       1 |       1 |             1
```

**Ошибка** - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: значение NULL в столбце "role_id" отношения "users_authorities" нарушает ограниче
ние NOT NULL
Подробности: Ошибочная строка содержит **(9, null, 1)**.

Я точно определил, что в метод репозиторий уходит пользователь с **заполненными данными**.

**Почему появляется null**?

Код по созданию отношения:

```
  @ManyToMany()
  @JoinTable(name = "users_authorities",  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
  private Collection<Role> roles;

  @ManyToMany()
  @JoinTable(name = "users_authorities", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id"))
  private Collection<Permission> permissions;
```

Comment: Вы понимаете, что такое изменение вводит зависимость между ролью и полномочием, которой раньше не было? а заодно приводит к нарушению нормальности данных - ибо если у пользователя будет несколько ролей/полномочий, то для каждой пары значений будет отдельная запись в таблице, т.е. дублирование по пользователю?

Comment: Спасибо! Честно говоря не понимал. Тогда лучше оставить две отдельные таблицы? users_roles и users_permissions?

Comment: Всё зависит от того, что описывает программа. Вариантов-то несколько. Может, должна существовать таблица, связывающая роль и разрешение, и связь её с таблицей пользователей... Выполните нормально анализ предметной области, постройте ER-диаграмму. А на пальцах можно прикидывать до бесконечности - и всё равно получить хрень.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!